# Mongoose Populate returns [Object] instead of result

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have an issue with the Population method from Mongoose. Following the structure below

```
const CompanySchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  logo: String,
  description: String,
  address: String,
  website: String,
  phone: String,
  email: String,
  warehouses: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CompanyWarehouses' }],
});

const CompanyWarehouses = new Schema({
  company: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company' },
  city: String,
});
```

I have some entries in both tables. I am trying to use the `Population` from `Mongoose` in order to populate the `warehouses` field for each company.

Using the following query

```
Company.find({}, 'warehouses -_id')
  .populate({
    path: 'warehouses',
  })
  .exec((err, docs) => {
     console.log(docs);
  });
```

I get the following results

```
[ { warehouses: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  { warehouses: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { warehouses: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { warehouses: [ [Object] ] },
  { warehouses: [] },
  { warehouses: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

If I do it the without the populate I get the Id's of the warehouses

```
[ { warehouses: 
     [ 5c2765e86351ec4f1e219d6b,
       5c2765e86351ec4f1e219d6c,
       5c2765e86351ec4f1e219d6d ] },
  { warehouses: [ 5c2773596351ec4f1e219d77, 5c2773596351ec4f1e219d78 ] },
  { warehouses: [ 5c277c766351ec4f1e219d82, 5c277c766351ec4f1e219d83 ] },
  { warehouses: [ 5c27843c6351ec4f1e219d90 ] },
  { warehouses: [] },
  { warehouses: [ 5c279b8ecebdea072f0bacd5 ] } ]
```

If I query the `CompanyWarehouses` and `populate` the `company` filed I get the population correct

```
CompanyWarehouses.find()
    .populate('company')
    .exec((err, docs) => {
      console.log(docs);
    });

[ { _id: 5c279b8ecebdea072f0bacd5,
    company: 
     { warehouses: [Array],
       _id: 5c279b3acebdea072f0baccc,
       name: 'sadsa',
       phone: '2323',
       email: 'sss@ss.ss',
       city: 'dsadsadsa',
       address: 'sadadsa',
       logo: 'logo.png' },
    city: 'ssdsa',
    __v: 0 }]
```

Can anyone please explain what am I missing here

LE:

I have defined both models like this

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', CompanySchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('CompanyWarehouses', CompanyWarehouses);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is caused by `console.log()` limiting the depth of the data it will show.

If you want to see the full contents of `docs`, you can log it as JSON:

```
console.log('%j', docs);
```

Or remove the depth limit:

```
const { inspect } = require('util');

...

console.log( inspect(docs, { depth : null }) );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have an even more complex population in the same app with 2 levels of population and there I did not get any [Object] issue so that's why I could not understand why it was not working. Actually it was working but  not showing as it should. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here

```
warehouses: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CompanyWarehouses' }]
```

you are giving value `CompanyWarehouses` to `ref`

Try to make the instance of both Schema Constant then assign that instance variable to `ref`

```
    const CompanySchema = new Schema({
      ...,
      warehouses: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'companywarehouses' }],
    });

    const CompanyWarehouses = new Schema({
      company: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'company' },
      ...
    });


   // instance of both Model
    const CompanySch = mongoose.model('company', CompanySchema);
    const WareHousesSch = mongoose.model('companywarehouses', CompanyWarehouses);
```

Comment: I have defined both models, please check my LE in the post

Comment: @Sabbin See the last two lines of my answer, You are not creating the `instance`, You are directly putting the model variable to `ref`